# Python 3.8.5 odd behavior when multiplying float by 100

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I am currently running python 3.8.5 and created a pandas DataFrame with some data. After performing some calculations I ended up with single float value, which was `.007`. I then multiplied the value by 100 to get the percent. However, I noticed that the value returned was `0.7000000000000001` instead of the expected `.7`. I have not tested in other python environments but have tried it in pycharm and jupyter lab. Bother return the same result.

So, I restarted the kernal and tried `print(.007*100)` and the returned result was the same. I also tried `print(.006*100)` and got the expected result: `.6`

Is this a bug in python 3.8.5? Has anyone else experienced / can replicate this issue?

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
​
print(.007*100)
print(.006*100)
print(.008*100)
0.7000000000000001
0.6
0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this a bug in python 3.8.5?*

This issue is not specific to version 3.8.5 and is caused by how `float`s in python works. Python [decimal module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) have discussion about that. You might use `decimal.Decimal` to avoid this problem, consider following example

```
import decimal
print(0.1+0.1+0.1==0.3)
print(decimal.Decimal("0.1")+decimal.Decimal("0.1")+decimal.Decimal("0.1")==decimal.Decimal("0.3"))
```

output

```
False
True
```

Comment: That fixes the issue. Thank you.